# How to use JavaScript in the WordPress menu

Tags: javascript, wordpress, menu

I want to design the wordpress menu so that clicking on a link will display another list.
From my research it is possible with java but I don't know how to use javascript in wordpress menu?

Here is the sample code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showhide(id){
if (document.getElementById){
obj = document.getElementById(id);
if (obj.style.display == "none"){
obj.style.display = "";
} else {
obj.style.display = "none";
}
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="showhide('a'); return(false);">a</a>
<div style="display: none;" id="a"> 
<ul>
<li>a 1</li>
<li>a 2</li>
<li>a 3</li>
</ul>
</div>
<a href="#" onclick="showhide('b'); return(false);">b</a>
<div style="display: none;" id="b"> 
<ul>
<li>b 1</li>
<li>b 2</li>
<li>b 3</li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use JavaScript by enqueue in function file or plugin file. This is a standard method in wordpress.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'handler_script', 'PATH OF YOUR JAVASCRIP FILE')
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/